# Custom Post Types relationships

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, functions

I have a custom post type for my videos. I need do related it with other post category. And i have 10 category

Like this :

```
Post Category - Video Category
Tech            Tech
Marketing       Marketing
News            News
.....................
```

I want to do for this. I have a post Category Tech and  I have custom post type Category(Taxonomy) Tech..

When I currently viewing Tech (Post) Category, How can i list (on sidebar) Tech videos?

Comment: Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/ - it allows for connecting post types and there are shortcodes and functions for listing them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @MarioPeshev, it is just about Post to Post i need Category(post category) to Category(Custom Post Taxonomy Term).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I gather your taxonomy term names match your category names. If this is the case and **always** will be the case, why not just query your custom post type by category slugs? Not sure what the exact name is, so I just made it `video`.

```
// get category slug
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_slug = $cat->slug;

// query your custom post type (video?), assuming 
// slugs match for your category name and taxonomy term name
$my_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $cat_slug
        )
    )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($my_args);

while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    // do the usual thing
}
```